# Android: prevent keyboard from hiding EditText

Tags: android, soft-keyboard

I have an `Activity` which its layout contains a `ScrollView` with several `Fragments` and some of the `Fragments` have `RecyclerView` which items in it contains `EditText` inside them.

I set the `android:windowSoftInputMode` to `stateHidden|adjustPan`.

It works most of the time well, but on some `EditTexts` the keyboard hides the text at first, but when starting to type it corrects itself and the screen jumps to the correct position.

UPDATE

I found out that it happens in `RecyclerView` and not in `ListView`